# Visiting the US under VWP as a C-Corp shareholder

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

I'm in a situation that I haven't read about, but imagine wouldn't be super uncommon.

I'm a co-founder of and own 50% of a C-Corp entity. My other founder is a US citizen who owns the remaining 50%. We're a remote company, and I work as a contractor from Australia.

Am I allowed to visit the US on the VWP to meet my co-founder in person? What would be the best explanation for this?

Cheers

Comment: Who pays your salary? The US entity, or someone else (eg, an Australian legal entity)?

Comment: The US entity pays me as a contractor. I don't have an Australian entity, as I'm operating as a sole trader.

Comment: I have incorporated myself into a one person company to avoid this situation. When asked at the border, I could answer the truth: I am employed by a Canadian company. No one ever asked whether I also own the company (yes) or whether there are other employees (no).